# How do i format a specific word/sentence inside jeditorpane?

Tags: java, jeditorpane

I am not a java expert. Just learning as i go.. This is my way! I am now designing a IDE for C++ (just fun, not professional) . I have the project almost ready, now i want to add some text highlighting function to the IDE. For example i want the IDE to recognize a predefined set of words and color them green,red. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use HTML, but you probably would be better off using the [TextAction](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TextAction.html) methods for a `JEditorPane`.

Another alternative is the [StyledDocument](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) interface.

Added because of the comment:  You can use the [StyledEditorKit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.html) class to see implementations of `TextAction`.

Here's Oracle's tutorial on [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).

Comment: can you give me a simple example of TextAction?

Comment: Can you give me simple example? I am lost.

Comment: If the Oracle tutorials are confusing, I suggest that you find a good Java Swing book.  There are Swing components that have to be used together to make a working Swing user interface.

Comment: Thank you .. I am currently on it.